# is it possible to add a Kernel Header file manually along with the kernel source and build

Tags: linux, kernel

I am using `Linux 2.6.18-238.e15`. In this kernel source I could not find the kernel header file `procinfo.h`. But my application requires this header file.

Is it possible to add this header file manually along with the kernel header files and rebuild the kernel?

If so, please let me know the procedures to do that?